# Regular expression intersection to exclude a char won't work

Tags: java, regex

I have some String in this form `[3 4.0:ad}` and I need to replace all whitespace and digit but `.` (that is needed to parse de float correctly)

so I have written this regular expression

```
\D*!.|\s+
```

but doesn't work and I haven't understood the right syntax I have used

`\D*` to select non digit characters

`!.` to exclude `.`from selection

`|\s+` to select all whitespace

If I remove the intersection `!.` works so something in the way I use it is wrong.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Just curious, where did you get the idea `!` is special? Is that from another regex syntax, or because of the negation or not-equal operators in the Java language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negated character class like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]+", "");
```

`[^\\d.]` will match any character that is not a digit and not a DOT.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oL2iC9/1)

btw `\D` also includes whitespace so both don't need to be provided in a regex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, anyway would be nice to learn how to use correctly the intersection to exclude a character from a selection. Could you tell me the right syntax for my approach?

Comment: You can use negative lookahead for that: [`str = str.replaceAll("(?:(?!\\.)\\D)+", "");`](https://regex101.com/r/oL2iC9/2) or simply: `str = str.replaceAll("(?!\\.)\\D", "");`

Answer (score 1):

As it says [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html), Java class *intersection*
is the subset of stuff in *class1* that is in *class2*.

Fairly simple concept, but usage can be tricky.
In the end, the compiler will resolve this into a single class, so if the
result is short and obvious, it will read better to do it yourself.

Example:

Not digits `\D`
Not dots `[^.]`

You want to match whitespace and that is part of not digits so no need to worry
about that.

Thus the intersection is `[\D&&[^.]]`
It reads as *Not Digits* and *Not Dots*.

The translation is `[^\d.]` which is what the compiler resolves it to.

The real power of intersection comes when you have a lot of holes within
a character range that you want to exclude.

For example, all letters except vowels `[a-z&&[^aeiou]]`